# How to configure Apache Hive?

Tags: apache, hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, hive

I use hadoop 2.6.0 to develop my mapreduce application. Beside it, I want to compare performance from mapreduce and Apache hive. So how can I configure an apache hive on the top of existing hadoop? And what the hive also run an mapreduce paradigm ?

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks mr devi for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes Hive runs the MapReduce paradigm.
For Hive Installation you can find the tutorial here :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

and here if you are more into videos :

http://www.hadoopscreencasts.com/episodes/4